# Insert a field within an image

Tags: html, css

I have an image and I want to insert a field for users to enter their email within it. 
Could you guys help me with the html code for it.

Thanks

Comment: What you really want? Post your code.

Comment: Try using the image as the background image for the div

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code..

```
    <img src="image.jpg" style="z-index:1"/>
    <input type="text" style="z-index:100;display:block;top:10px;position:absolute;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this will help you?

HTML

```
​<div class="inputDiv">
<input type="text" value="input your data here"/>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS

```
.inputDiv{
    background:url(your_pic_url.jpg) no-repeat;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}

.inputDiv input{position:absolute; top:50px; left:50px;}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g4Ujc/)